# ModuleNotFound error after sucessfully install cgal using conda?

Tags: anaconda, conda, cgal, conda-forge

I installed CGAL in windows using conda: 
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cgal
But it gives error during importing modules.

```
>>> import CGAL
>>> print(CGAL.__version__)
4.14.0
>>> import CGAL.CGAL_AABB_tree
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah\.conda\envs\CGALCONDA\lib\site-packages\CGAL\CGAL_AABB_tree.py", line 14, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module(mname)
  File "C:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah\.conda\envs\CGALCONDA\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 658, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 571, in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 922, in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah\.conda\envs\CGALCONDA\lib\site-packages\CGAL\CGAL_AABB_tree.py", line 17, in <module>
    _CGAL_AABB_tree = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah\.conda\envs\CGALCONDA\lib\site-packages\CGAL\CGAL_AABB_tree.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_CGAL_AABB_tree')
  File "C:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah\.conda\envs\CGALCONDA\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_CGAL_AABB_tree'
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the output of `conda list -n CGALCONDA cgal`?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not the `ModuleNotFoundError`, but the underlying `ImportError: DLL load failed:`. Looking at your error message, you can see that your python does succesfully locate what you are trying to import at

```
C:\Users\Ibrahim Khalilullah\.conda\envs\CGALCONDA\lib\site-packages\CGAL\CGAL_AABB_tree.py
```

but fails to load a dependent DLL.

I have reproduced your issue. It seems to be one that only effects the most current of `cgal` in conda forge, which is 4.14 When you install the `4.13` version everything works fine, so simply do:

```
conda remove cgal
conda install -c conda-forge cgal==4.13
```

I have created an issue on the conda-forge [feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/cgal-feedstock/issues/55)